# SQL create an array from several rows

Tags: mysql, join, hive, self-join

I have a table with a one to many mapping from `ID` to `some_value`. What query can give me all of `some_value` for a particular `ID`?

I can use any array, string, or other object useful in SQL as the final result in `list_of_values`. You don't need to use my comma seperated format.

My particular varient of SQL is Hive, but the syntax and functions are very similar to MySQL :)

Starting table:

```
ID             some_value
-----------    ------------
1              a
1              b
1              c
2              x
2              y
2              z
2              a
3              g
3              h
```

Finished table:

```
ID              list_of_values
----------      ----------------
1               a, b, c
2               x, y, z, a
3               g, h
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, COLLECT_SET(some_value) AS list_of_values
    FROM YourTable 
    GROUP BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    `id`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `some_value` SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'list_of_values'
FROM `your_table`
GROUP BY `id`
```